# Display two custom values from a post

Tags: custom-field

I'm using the following code to display a custom value. The custom value being 'website'

```
<?php
  $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post_id); //Current post id
  $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['website']; //key name
  foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value )
  echo $key . " => <a href='" . $value . "'>Click Here</a><br />";
?>
```

However, before the 'Click here' i'd like to include another custom value, thumb.

So the output would be:

```
Value of custom field thumb
Value of custom field website
```

Thanks.

Comment: So i've managed to come up with a workaround. Used two similar functions, one above the other. Maybe this isn't the right way, so if anyone has a cleaner suggestion, let me know.

`<?php
  $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post_id); //Current post id
  $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['thumb']; //key name
  foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value )
  echo "<img src='" . $value . "'>";
?>`

Which did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$thumb = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'thumb', true );
$url = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'website', true);
echo "<a href='$url'><img src='$thumb' /></a>";
```

The `get_post_meta()` function is ideal when you know ahead-of-time the names of the fields you want to retrieve. Setting the third parameter to `true` tells it that you want to return a single value, and not an array of values (it's possible to set multiple values using the same meta key, and get an array of values back).

Comment: What happens if one of those values comes back as empty? Might i suggest ... `if( $thumb && $url )` prior to the echo.